# nsmutablearray leaking the memory iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I have an nsmutablearray which i need through out the application so i declared it in application delegate and release it in dealloc method of application delegate. Here is the code for that.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *arr1;
    IBOutlet UINavigationController *navConroller;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navConroller;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arr1;


@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize navConroller;
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize arr1;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:navConroller.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.arr1 release];
    [_window release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

when i check memory performance tool it shows me memory leak at

```
self.arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I am using this array in different classes. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I used Pieter Gunst answer and leak stop at that place. but it is showing at another place. where i pares json and storing records in arr1. Here is the code for that.

```
-(void) apiCall:(NSString *)para1 {
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

    para1 = [para1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    para1 = [para1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *url = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"my api url",para1] autorelease];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

    arr1 = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

    [json_string release];
    [parser release];
```

}

Now leak shows at following line.

```
arr1 = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: it does not seem to be leaked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have allocated array and also retained it by accessing property.
Change below line of code;

```
self.arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

with either of any below line..

```
arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

OR

```
self.arr1 = [NSMutableArray array];
```

OR

```
NSMutableArray *tArr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.arr1 = tArr1;
[tArr1 release];
```

Comment: @BoA you're wrong. He's using non-arc. In ARC code you never call [super dealloc];

Comment: @tikhop I've been coding too much Android recently, perhaps he isn't. But anyway, he was releasing it in dealloc so there shouldn't be an autorelease there anyway.

Comment: @BoA Yeah, however if you see "strong" attribute in the code this doesn't mean that the code use ARC. strong equivalent to retain in non-ARC code

Comment: @tikhop Yeah, I realised that.

Comment: i tried both this post self.arr1 = [NSMutableArray array]; and @synthesize arr1 = _arr1; and _arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   both are working well. I am not getting the difference. can any one explain ?

Comment: NSMutableArray *tArr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.arr1 = tArr1;
[tArr1 release];
This help me to stop leaking.

Answer (score 1):

Try `@synthesize arr1 = _arr1;` and `_arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried both this post self.arr1 = [NSMutableArray array]; and @synthesize arr1 = _arr1; and _arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; both are working well. I am not getting the difference. can you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

As Apurv already mentioned use

```
self.arr1 = [NSMutableArray array];
```

or

```
self.arr1 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Also make all properties of same type (don't mix strong and retain):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)
```

And for dealloc method use automatically generated getter/setter:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.arr1 = nil;
    self.window = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Hints:

Topic starter does not use ARC, because of

```
[super dealloc];
```

cause error "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealloc'"